# Restangular - Incrementing and updating a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean, restangular

I'm using Restangular with a MEAN stack, my api is running on localhost:3000.

I want to increment 'views' every time the page is loaded.
currently I'm getting the object and setting it to a value like 1000, and this works fine, but when I try to increment it it doesn't work.

```
angular.module('clientApp').controller('MovieViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Movie) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        var passReq = Movie.one($routeParams.id);
        passReq.views = 1000;
        passReq.put();
    });
    $scope.viewMovie = true;
    $scope.movie = Movie.one($routeParams.id).get().$object;
});
```

^^ This works

```
angular.module('clientApp').controller('MovieViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Movie) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        var passReq = Movie.one($routeParams.id);
        passReq.views++;
        passReq.put();
    });
    $scope.viewMovie = true;
    $scope.movie = Movie.one($routeParams.id).get().$object;
});
```

But this doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `passReq.views` isn't defined so you can't increment an undefined variable, do this:

```
angular.module('clientApp').controller('MovieViewCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, Movie) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        var passReq = Movie.one($routeParams.id);
        if (passReq.views)        
           passReq.views++;
        else
           passReq.views = 1;
        passReq.put();
    });
    $scope.viewMovie = true;
    $scope.movie = Movie.one($routeParams.id).get().$object;
});
```

Comment: It's doing the same as before, views gets a NULL value

Answer (score 0):

sometime MEAN can not handle *increment operator* that I faced.
so you can try

```
if(passReq.views)
    passReq.views += 1;
```

Comment: I have tried that before, but that also doesn't work.